# Remove a link in the header

Tags: headers

I don't know why but in the header I've always have the **page name** and that thing below **'-> page name'**. How can I get rid of it?

[image]

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is something that's theme-driven, so you're either going to have to see if you can change this via the theme **settings** or you're going to have to ask help via the **theme support**.